# Issue in Aligning two Div Horizontally

Tags: css, html

I was trying to align the two div **sec-name** and **sec-filters** horizontally.

Here is the css:

```
div.sec-head {
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    border: 1px solid #AFAFAF;
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 12px;
    height: 24px;
}
.sec-filters {
    float: right;
    //margin-top: -20px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-top: 4px;
}
.clear-float {
    clear: both;
}
```

The problem is the div on the right(sec-filters) lie below the left div sec-name. I am expecting the two div to align horizontally.

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="sec-head clear-float">
    <div class="sec-name">Heading</div>
    <div class="sec-filters">
        <a href="#">1</a>
        <a href="#">2</a>
        <a href="#">3</a>
        <a href="#">4</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

**[JS-FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/9SdNZ/1/)**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `display:table` to parent and `display:table-cell` to child divs:

http://jsfiddle.net/9SdNZ/6/

Answer (score 2):

Option 1:

```
.sec-name,.sec-filters {    
    display:inline-block;
    width:50%;
}
.sec-filters{
    text-align:right;
}
```

[**DEMO fiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/hiral/9SdNZ/4/)

Option 2:

```
.sec-name {
    float:left;
}
.sec-filters {
    float:right;
}
```

[**DEMO here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/hiral/9SdNZ/8/)

Answer (score 1):

Try adding

```
div.sec-head {
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    border: 1px solid #AFAFAF;
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 12px;
    height: 24px;
    vertical-align:top;
}
.sec-filters {
    float: right;
    //margin-top: -20px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    display:inline;
}
.clear-float {
    clear: both;
}
.sec-name{
    display:inline;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

By default the divs have width: 100%. If you want to use float to make them appear in a line, add they width. For example add to both width: 40%, and all will be peachy. Also I suggest float: left on both instead of 1 float left and 1 float right... but that's just a matter of taste.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to float the div, one way is "to free" the div : **position:absolute;**

and to put "the absoluted" div inside parent ".sec-head" set parent's position to **relative**

css:

```
div.sec-head {
    position:relative;
}

.sec-filters {
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    right:0px;
}
```